# iOS MobileFirst 7.1 Application giving error while worklight connection

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We have created iOS and Android application using Worklight 6.1. Recently we migrated it to Mobile First 7.1.

After doing migration the android application is working fine. But in iOS we are getting below error. Due to which application giving error for

```
WL.Client.connect({
                    onSuccess: onConnectSuccessMFS,
                    onFailure: onConnectFailureMFS
             });
```

And here `onConnectFailureMFS` function is getting called due to connection was not established.

```
  2016-11-24 16:24:24.902 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/winjit-suyog/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85363033-091B-4B86-8543-815FE0C47D8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/3A4AA94E-4325-4BFB-9106-D3932FF84305/Library/Cookies/com.xxx.mobilebankingiphone.binarycookies
2016-11-24 16:24:25.078 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:189 :: Splash screen image is taken from UILaunchImages: Default-667h
2016-11-24 16:24:25.184 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:189 :: Splash screen image is taken from UILaunchImages: Default-667h
2016-11-24 16:24:25.186 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7fc87341d920>.
2016-11-24 16:24:25.201 XXXXXXXX[16439:164046] [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:71 :: {
    "application id" = "xxx_iBank";
    "application version" = "4.0";
    authenticitySharedData = "${authenticitySharedData}";
    buildtime = 1479984854;
    environment = iphone;
    host = "hostname";
    ignoredFileExtensions = "";
    platformVersion = "7.1.0.0";
    port = 443;
    protocol = https;
    testWebResourcesChecksum = false;
    wlAppFamily = "";
    wlMainFile = "index.html";
    wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = "";
    wlServerContext = "/qa/";
    wlShareCookies = "";
    wlShareUserCert = false;
    wlUid = "kGGREBVfLjxh/6KrBskjhg==";
}
2016-11-24 16:24:25.202 XXXXXXXX[16439:164046] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:126 :: At first launch
2016-11-24 16:24:25.203 XXXXXXXX[16439:164046] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:152 :: Web resources should not be extracted.
2016-11-24 16:24:26.605 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting.
2016-11-24 16:24:26.605 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-11-24 16:24:26.622 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Unlimited access to network resources
2016-11-24 16:24:26.624 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file

2016-11-24 16:24:26.628 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.116050ms
2016-11-24 16:24:26.629 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [CDVTimer][push] 0.171006ms
2016-11-24 16:24:26.629 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.751972ms
2016-11-24 16:24:26.745 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-11-24 16:24:29.532 XXXXXXXX[16439:164028] [WARN] [NONE] Initialization option 'connectOnStartup' is deprecated. Use WL.Client.connect() to connect to the IBM MobileFirst Platform Server.
2016-11-24 16:24:29.538 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] log1
2016-11-24 16:24:29.597 XXXXXXXX[16439:163999] [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event dispatched
2016-11-24 16:24:29.598 XXXXXXXX[16439:164008] [WARN] [NONE] Initialization option 'analytics' is deprecated. Use WL.Analytics.enable/disable to set analytics data capture.
2016-11-24 16:24:29.599 XXXXXXXX[16439:164095] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started
2016-11-24 16:24:29.600 XXXXXXXX[16439:164093] [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null
2016-11-24 16:24:29.600 XXXXXXXX[16439:164094] [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
2016-11-24 16:24:29.612 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:29.619 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '75.402832' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-11-24 16:24:29.620 XXXXXXXX[16439:164093] [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess
2016-11-24 16:24:29.622 XXXXXXXX[16439:164093] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2016-11-24 16:24:29.624 XXXXXXXX[16439:164093] [DEBUG] [NONE] after: initOptions.onSuccess
2016-11-24 16:24:29.625 XXXXXXXX[16439:164008] [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause and onResume event handlers
2016-11-24 16:24:29.626 XXXXXXXX[16439:164095] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success
2016-11-24 16:24:29.627 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.xxx.mobilebankingiphone
2016-11-24 16:24:29.627 XXXXXXXX[16439:164094] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:29.632 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:29.729 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '96.157959' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-11-24 16:24:29.755 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:30.009 XXXXXXXX[16439:164008] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2016-11-24 16:24:30.010 XXXXXXXX[16439:164093] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/xxx_iBank/iphone/init]
2016-11-24 16:24:30.039 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:30.040 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager invokeInstanceRegistrationRequestWithCompletionHandler:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: Call instance registration endpoint
2016-11-24 16:24:30.043 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:30.279 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:225 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success
2016-11-24 16:24:30.286 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:30.292 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-11-24 16:24:30.310 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
2016-11-24 16:24:30.315 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:30.323 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
{
    "Accept-Language" = en;
    "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXX/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "4B0C5DE7-6507-46B5-98A8-A455BB43BC5C";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
}
You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
2016-11-24 16:24:30.326 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-11-24 16:24:30.327 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x7fc8734065c0>{number = 1, name = main})
2016-11-24 16:24:30.328 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '573.004883' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-11-24 16:24:39.274 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
2016-11-24 16:24:39.275 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
2016-11-24 16:24:39.276 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Could not connect to the server.
2016-11-24 16:24:39.277 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:39.277 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:509 :: Status code='0' error='Could not connect to the server.' response='(null)'
2016-11-24 16:24:39.278 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:512 :: Response Header: (null)
Response Data: (null)
2016-11-24 16:24:39.279 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
2016-11-24 16:24:39.282 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-11-24 16:24:39.285 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-11-24 16:24:39.288 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:39.295 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:39.300 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:39.301 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager invokeInstanceRegistrationRequestWithCompletionHandler:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: Call instance registration endpoint
2016-11-24 16:24:39.301 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:39.328 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:225 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success
2016-11-24 16:24:39.333 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:39.334 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-11-24 16:24:39.335 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
2016-11-24 16:24:39.336 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
2016-11-24 16:24:39.337 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
{
    "Accept-Language" = en;
    "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXX/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "4B0C5DE7-6507-46B5-98A8-A455BB43BC5C";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
}
You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
2016-11-24 16:24:39.347 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://hostname:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-11-24 16:24:39.349 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x7fc8734065c0>{number = 1, name = main})
2016-11-24 16:24:39.349 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '53.093750' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-11-24 16:24:40.836 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] Finished load of: file:///Users/winjit-suyog/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85363033-091B-4B86-8543-815FE0C47D8D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2F150F10-8D15-4AB7-8B7B-A867EDB1BA1D/XXXXXXXX.app/www/default/index.html#menu
2016-11-24 16:24:45.081 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
2016-11-24 16:24:45.082 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
2016-11-24 16:24:45.083 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Could not connect to the server.
2016-11-24 16:24:45.084 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
2016-11-24 16:24:45.084 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:509 :: Status code='0' error='Could not connect to the server.' response='(null)'
2016-11-24 16:24:45.085 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:512 :: Response Header: (null)
Response Data: (null)
2016-11-24 16:24:45.086 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
2016-11-24 16:24:45.089 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-11-24 16:24:45.092 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-11-24 16:24:45.095 XXXXXXXX[16439:163898] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
```

We tried with different solutions available on SO. But not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enabled TLS 1.2 on the server an have configured ATS in iOS to connect via HTTPS, as this is now a requirement in production systems.

If this is during development then you can disable ATS to continue development.

Read more here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

Comment: We already followed this link but still getting issue. For localhost it is working fine.

Comment: It could be that you have misconfigured the URL.

Comment: I observed this log "Invalid response when registering application". Can u please tell me why im getting this. This response come after some time below the above mentioned log

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue unique to iOS 11 and one of our applications running on apache2.

Try to disable HTTP2 on your web server. Once I disabled it in my virtual host, the site started to behave normally again.